# String manipulation in javascript (remove leading zero & specific character)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

```
var patt = path.match(/P[0-9][0-9][0-9]/);
patt = patt.substr(1);  //Remove P

while(patt.charAt(0) === '0') {   //Remove 0
    patt = patt.substr(1);
}

alert(patt);
```

`patt` is fixed to this format:
eg. `P001` to `P999`

What I would like to do is very basic, just remove `P` and the  leading `0` (if any). However, the code above is not working. Thanks for helping

Comment: If you remove leading zeroes would you not end up with `P1` in your first example?

Comment: Surely you're getting an exception on the `patt = patt.substr(1)` line? The return value of `String#match` is an array, not a string; it has no `substr` method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the result is 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please use it like this:

> var str = patt.join('');
>   str = str.replace(/P0*/, '');

Answer (score 1):

If the input to this function is guaranteed to be valid (i.e. of the form P001...P999), then you can simply use the following to extract the integer:

```
parseInt(path.substr(1), 10)
```

Comment: Default base for parseInt is 10 for all modern browsers (as of ECMAScript 5). But edited answer to explicitly set radix to 10, for clarity, and for older browsers.

Comment: sorry, problem is that javascript interprets numbers with trailing 0 as radix 8, parseInt isn't the problem, you are right, still stuff like `parseInt('084')` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems the perfect use case for the global [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

```
parseInt(patt.substr(1), 10);
```

It takes as input the string you want to parse, and the base.
The base is optional, but most people suggest to always explicitly set the base to avoid surprises which may happen in some edge case.

It stops to parse the string as soon as it encounters a not numerical value (blank spaces excluded).
For this reason in the snippet above we're a passing the input string stripped of the first character, that as you've mentioned, is the letter "P".

Also, ES2015 introduced a `parseInt` function, as static method on the `Number` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just a single line and you get what you want

```
var path = "P001"; //your code from P001 - P999
```

solution to remove P and the leading "0" .

```
parseInt(path.substr(1), 10);
```

Thanks and Regards